# How to handle module-wide variables, which need to be initialized before use?

Tags: python-3.x, anti-patterns

I was looking through an open source project and found a lot of this type of code:

```
import something

error_path = None

def set_error_path(path):
  global error_path

  error_path = path

def get_error_path():
  return error_path
```

So some kind of singleton module in a way.

This could, of course, throw exceptions if the user doesn't call the setter, before the getter. But giving `error_path` a different initial value is also not possible, because `""` could be a valid value.

In general I would think that the `error_path` would have to be part of whatever structure calls the functions, be it an `App` object or something else, but since that seems not to be wanted/possible how could this be written better?

Comment: While the question is subjective, initialising *is* a feature of classes, not modules. This should not be a "singleton module" which can be in an inconsistent state, but a (singleton) class that is by construction in a consistent state.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I was hoping that it might be an anti-pattern with a name and an accepted "fix".

Comment: Perhaps this matches: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_coupling